# sequence with almost surely convergence & moment of order 2

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let's say we have iid random variables $(X_n)$ s.t. $X_1$ admits a moment of order 2.
For $n \geq 1$, does the following sequence converge almost surely or not? Why? And how to see/show?

$$A_n = \frac{X_1X_2 + X_2X_3 + \cdots + X_{n-1}X_n}{n} $$

Comment: Note that the expectation converges to $\mu^2$ and the variance is $O(1/n)$. (In the intermediate calculation of the variance of $A_n$, the contribution of the terms of the form $X_i X_j X_k X_l $ disappears.) I guess this may help you investigate the convergence of $A_n$. (Indeed, I am thinking that mimicking Kolmogorov's argument would yield the a.s. convergence.)

Comment: easier:  do $X_1X_2 + X_3X_4 + ... $ and $X_2X_3 + X_4X_5 ...$ separately

Comment: @sos440: Kolmogorov's argument? But how? :S And what is u²?

Comment: @mike: How do you mean this?

Comment: the first and second series are both sums of i.i.d.s, $\frac {X_1X_2 + X_3X_4 + ... X_{2n+1}X_{2n}}n \rightarrow  \frac 12 $$E(X_1X_2)$ by ordinary SLLN. More specifically $X_1X_2 $ and $X_3X_4$ *are* i.i.d.

Comment: Ok, so in that case, $A_n \rightarrow E(X_1 X_2) $ ?
And what "SLLN" means?